# Keeping the html color input empty when no action is taken

Tags: php, html, input, colors

I believe it is common practice to predicate an action in PHP on whether a variable that comes from an HTML input field is empty. At least I do it all the time. Like

```
If ( $_POST['whatever'] != '' ){ 
   echo 'Hi there'; 
}
```

I'm running into a problem with the HTML 5 color picker, which apparently defaults to black, always equals a color and therefore cannot be subjected to this test of anything like it. Am I missing something?

My application here is that I have a template with default colors and I am creating user overrides. The problem is that if the user changes one color, all the colors in that form save as black. I realize that I can preload my default colors, but I'm just wondering if this can work another way because the overrides can apply to various templates, so it would be nice to have them be "default agnostic".

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a way you could set another default value for the color picker? So that it returns nothing if no color has been set?

Comment: Thanks OSI. From what I understand the color input always returns something. So setting it first to the default seems to be the only way to address this.

Comment: Isn't there not any method or callback to detect if the value has been changed? You could also try to hook into the drag event or something similar, to detect a change.

Comment: Here's how I got around this: a jquery color picker populates the input.